# Crafter CMS 2.5.x Looking for user who trigger a publish to live

Tags: crafter-cms

I'm currently working on a custom post processor for the crafter deployer that takes some information from the files to publish to the live server and make an integration with an external system. The thing I missing is the information (username and email) of the person who actually approved the publishing of the documents in the workflow.

We are working with Alfresco as the content repository for our implementation.